# Can Time Machine volumes be easily encrypted with FileVault 2?

Tags: time-machine, macos, external-disk, filevault

Now that File Vault 2 can encrypt the entire disk and encrypt external drives, can I have a fully encrypted Time Machine volume?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Lion features page](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/features.html#timemachine), encrypted backups are supported.

Comment: Use the Time Machine pane of System Preferences to enable encryption for the volume.

Answer (score 5):

[Daniel Jalkut's blog](http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/) today has a post that may be what you're looking for.

http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/1935/lions-whole-disk-encryption

Apparently, this:

```
% diskutil cs convert /Volumes/Data -passphrase [yourPasswordHere]
```

I haven't tried this yet, I just got Lion installed about an hour ago. Any destruction of your system is on your own head.