# How to create a pseudo-guest account in Lion with FileVault 2?

Tags: macos, permission, filevault, guest-account

The guest account always had very limited permissions, unfortunately since activating FileVault on Lion it's deactivated by default. (More about it here: [Unable to create Guest Account after enabling FileVault](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18205/unable-to-create-guest-account-after-enabling-filevault).)

Is it possible to give the guest account a password? Or can I create a regular account with the normal guest account's privileges (hence making a pseudo-guest account)?

I simply need FileVault and a limited account for my guest! :)

Comment: You can now create Guest logins in Lion - 
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29206

Answer (score 1):

## Guest Account

This account is visible in Directory Utility, but please do not attempt to make it compatible with FileVault 2. Not only for security; there may be other good reasons for Apple making this account not available whilst FileVault 2 is enabled.

## Other accounts

For your guest you might like to create a standard account, or add parental controls. You can probably have an account that is password-free. This is in line with [Kyle Cronin's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18205/unable-to-create-guest-account-after-enabling-filevault/18304#18304) to a linked question.

### Recommended reading

[Apart from being able to encypt an entire volume, what are the other differences of FileVault 2 over FileVault?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/17889/8546)

Comment: actually, no, you can NOT create password-free accounts of any type (admin, standard, or Parental Controlled) once FileVault is enabled. If you could, the guest account wouldn't be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the OS X server tools package, you can use the Users and Groups application to modify user's rights, even on OS X Client.

There are quite a few options to lock it down in various ways, depends on your exact requirements for locking it down.

So, I would just create a regular account and configure it to run the way you'd like.