# Is there a way to DISABLE a user from decrypting the boot volume?

Tags: macos, filevault

I see a very well documented way, if a user is *not* enabled to decrypt the boot volume, to enable that user: just go into the FileVault control panel, and if there are users not permitted to boot the system, there will be a message so-indicating, and a button that will bring up a dialog for enabling them.

I have the converse problem: I have a user FileVault-enabled user, who should *NOT* be.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is the documented way you have seen? Which article/page/site is it?

Comment: Possible dupe : https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/18358/489896

Comment: @Thinkr: Thanks. Accordingly, I just added a cross-reference as an answer, and voted to close my own question.

Comment: @hbquikcomjamesl Very nice reaction.

Comment: @Allan: It does indeed. See my reply to Thinkr's question. Dunno whether it works on Catalina or Ventura, but I can certainly confirm the assertion by Rafael Bugajewski (in the other thread) that it works just fine on Yosemite.

Comment: You can flag it as a dupe and it will automatically link.  The answer will likely be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a duplicate of [Disable a user's ability to unlock a FileVault 2 volume at startup/login time](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/18358/489896), i.e., `sudo fdesetup remove -user username`

Comment: Excellent! Well close this and your words will help others search and know the questions are solved with the same answer. +1