# How can I downgrade from Mountain Lion to Lion?

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to Lion from Mountain Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57403/how-to-revert-to-lion-from-mountain-lion)

How can I downgrade from Mountain Lion to Lion ? I need to download Lion again... thanks

Comment: Do you want to turn this into "under what circumstances can I re-download the Lion installer? It might need some details or you could leave it very generic and let us provide a general answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do a complete backup with time machine, then formatting, install lion and restore all the data (including application and preferences) from time machine backup.

If you cannot download lion from app store, you have to search it on the web....

Comment: If you purchased Lion in the Mac App Store you can still download it from the purchases tab.